# app inventor 2 POST

Tags: php, android, http, post, app-inventor

I want to integrate a `webviewer` component in an `appinventor` app.

I want the app to `POST` something to already prepared `PHP` script. I do not want to use `GET`. So `PHP` on server looks like:

```
<?php echo $_POST['value']; ?>
```

My `appinventor` block looks like:

[image]

This is NOT working. Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT**: 2nd try. Thank you @YiWei.
[image]

Comment: the suggestion of @YiWei looks fine. What do you get in the `Web1.GotText` event?

Answer (score 4):

add `requestheaders:content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `buildrequestData`

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the image somewhere else and link it here? I really wonder if there is any working solution for this.

Comment: I tried with no luck... can you please check my code? http://s9.postimg.org/p0riiv7qn/V_st_i_ek.png

Answer (score 2):

the `webviewer` only can do `GET`
this should work:

[image]

using the `web` component, you get the result back in the `Web.GotText` event
[image]

see also the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/connectivity.html#Web)

Comment: This, of course, is working. But I do not want to use get. So you mean, that it is not possible to send the data through POST? Is there any other way to send security sensitive data from app to web?

Comment: just use only the `web`component as you did in the example, there is no need to use a `webviewer` component...

Comment: but i want the viewer to be part of the app. How can I get back the result if I use the POST? Any working example?